# Install cx_freeze on anaconda?

Tags: python, cx-freeze, anaconda

I'm trying to install cx_freeze to a virtual environment I've made in anaconda.  From within the environment, I type (https://binstar.org/pyzo/cx_freeze):

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/pyzo cx_freeze
```

I get the following message:

```
Fetching package metadata: ...
Solving package specifications: ..
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.
Generating hint: 
[2/2                 ] |#####################################################################################################################################################################################| 100%

Hint: the following combinations of packages create a conflict with the
remaining packages:
  - python 2.7*
  - cx_freeze
```

I'm using anaconda 3.7.4 on python version 2.7.9 on linux-64 Ubuntu 14.

Comment: That channel only has cx_Freeze packages for Python 3 ([see files](https://binstar.org/pyzo/cx_freeze/files)). If you want to use it with Python 2, you'll either need to make a conda package for cx_Freeze with Python 2, or `conda install pip` into your environment and use that to install cx_Freeze.

Comment: Thanks.  If you want to add this as an answer, I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case `conda install` cannot install a package because there is a conflict with the version of Python you use:

- make sure pip is installed in your current (virtual) Python environment: `conda install pip` (or `conda list` to see whether pip is in the list of installed packages)
- install your package using pip: `pip install <name of your package>`